# Behaviour of @Post callback methods i.e. @PostUpdate, @PostCreate etc. in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa, callback, jpa-2.0

> Hi All,
>
> > I am not able to understand the exact behavior of @Post callback methods. As mention in ProJPA book "When the SQL for deletion of an entity finally does get sent to the database, the PostRemove event will get fired. As with the PostPersist lifecycle event, the PostRemove event does not guarantee success. The enclosing transaction may still be rolled back".
> >
> > My concern here is, if SQL DELETE statement is already fire then how transaction will be rolled back? If SQL DELETE statement is not able to delete the object then exception will be thrown and @PostDelete will not be executed. So, under what scenario transaction can be rolled back??
> >
> > Thanks all for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According JPA specifications: the @PostRemove callback is executed after the *remove operation on the EntityManager*.

The key point to understand is that the *remove operation on the EntityManager* won't throw an exception if the remove fail. The transaction may be marked as "Rollback-Only" (i.e. it means that the transaction will be roll-backed when the transaction ends... and the exception will be thrown **at the end** of the transaction).

The JPA specifications indicates that the @PostRemove callback will be executed (in the same transaction as the *remove operation* of course) regardless of the flag "Rollback-Only".

It means that you can perform additional database operation in the @PostRemove : those operations will be part of the same transaction (and so will also be rollbacked if something went wrong). And the corollary : if something flag the transaction as rollback-only during the @PostRemove : the remove operation will not be executed on your database.